# adding multiple image in django model

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add multiple images to a django model, it works in admin but i am completely blank on how to show it on my template. here is what i tried, it doesn't give any error but the image doesn't show.

**models.py**

```
class Export_Trade_Data(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(
        BannerandInformation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    # country_name = models.CharField('Country Name', max_length=100, default='')
    trade_text = models.TextField('Text for Trade Data', null=True)
    # date added
    date_added = models.DateTimeField('Date Updated', auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Export Trade Data"


class ExportImage(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(
        BannerandInformation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    export_trade_data = models.ForeignKey(Export_Trade_Data, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    export_sample_image = models.ImageField(
        'Export Sample Image', upload_to='country', null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return "Export Trade Data"
```

**views.py**

```
def country(request, country):
    exch_val = ''
    banners = BannerandInformation.objects.filter(country=country)
    for b in banners:
        country_name = b
        exch_r = b.exch_rate
        exch_cur = exch_r.split("/")[0]

######Export_Trade_Data Model#######
    etrds = Export_Trade_Data.objects.filter(country_id=ct_id)
######ExportImage Model#######
    expics = ExportImage.objects.filter(country_id=ct_id)
    for s in expics:
        etd_pic = s.export_sample_image

    content = {
        "etrds": etrds,
        "etd_pic": etd_pic,

    }
    return render(request, 'country/country-page.html', content)
```

**country-page.html**

```
<tbody>
  {% for expics in etrds %}
  <tr>
    <img src="/country/{{expics.export_sample_image}}" height="604px" width="527px" alt="">
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Comment: can you show what does the template receives from the view ? like an array of image objects or just single object or something

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have relevant `ExportImage` queryset in the context, you should be able to render it this way:

```
  {% for ei in export_images %}
    <img src="{{ei.export_sample_image.url}}">
  {% endfor %}
```

However, seeing your view code it's unclear what you're trying to do there. I suggest you rewrite it. The part that should get your images would look like this:

```
def country(request, country_id):
    export_images = ExportImage.objects.filter(country_id=country_id)
    return render(request, 
                  'country/country-page.html', 
                  {'export_images': export_images})
```